# Convert click info to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, circular-reference

I am trying to convert click information to a JSON for storage using

```
$(document).click(function(e){
  url = '/recordclick';
  $.post(url, {'clickData':JSON.stringify(e)});
});
```

but it seems that the click event has one or more circular references in it because I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Is there a way to easily convert the click event into something without circular references, that is, without manually removing each of the circular referencing properties?

Comment: Don't do that. What part of the event do you actually need?

Comment: why you need to stringify such big event object into json?

Comment: why not just create an object with only the stuff you need and then do the JSON.stringify

Comment: @SLaks Not sure what information will be most useful to our machine learning algorithm, so I'm trying to save as much as possible. Storage space is not an issue.

Comment: @KhaledGarbaya That is what I want to do, but without knowing what I need a priori.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that javascript provides to do this for you all the way. Maybe you could use JSON.stringify's [replacer parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) to remove specific things from the stringification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use **Douglas Crockford**'s `JSON.decycle` function to make a deep copy of the event object before encoding it to JSON.

Souce code here: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js

Here is a quote from the source code of the function's description

> **Make a deep copy of an object or array**, assuring that there is at most one instance of each object or array in the resulting structure. The duplicate references (***which might be forming cycles***) are replaced with an object of the form `{"$ref": PATH}` where the `PATH` is a JSONPath string that locates the first occurance. [...]

As you've included `JSON.decycle` your code can be adjusted like this:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    var url = '/recordclick', // let's declare variables as local!
        dec = JSON.decycle(e);
    $.post(url, { 'clickData': JSON.stringify(dec) });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the stringify function accepts a filter function as a second param, so I think you can do this.

```
JSON.stringify( event, function( key, value) {
  if( key == 'circularReference1' || key == 'circularReference2') { return value.id;}
  else {return value;}
}
```

Comment: This assumes I have a list ('circularReference1', 'circularReference2', etc.) of circular references, correct?

Comment: Exactly, you can get the list easily by checking the event object, mostly are DOM elements that is referenced in the event like parent etc ...